# Attempt to install perlbrew fails

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I'm attempting to install perlbrew via

```
\curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

as suggested from https://perlbrew.pl

However, I get these errors

```
print() on closed filehandle $fh at perlbrew.Yyb5zU line 1569.
print() on closed filehandle $fh at perlbrew.Yyb5zU line 1569.
print() on closed filehandle $fh at perlbrew.Yyb5zU line 1569.
```

There are so many of those error lines, I can't even see anything else before them.

```
Fail to create /usr/local/perlbrew/etc/bashrc. Please check the permission of /usr/local/perlbrew/etc and try `perlbrew init` again. at perlbrew.Yyb5zU line 1462
```

I manually created directories in `/usr/local/perlbrew`, but this isn't a good idea, and it didn't fix the problem.

this is a redHat system, so I can't install via `yum` either.

How can I successfully install `perlbrew` on this redHat server?

Comment: What shell are you using? Try to set `SHELL` explicitly like this: `curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | SHELL=/bin/bash bash`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I am using bash, the command that you wrote did not work :(

Comment: No idea why, but the errors are the result of this failing: `my $executable = $0; open my $fh, "<", $executable;`

Comment: Maybe there's something special about the directory used during the installation. You could try `( export TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp"; mkdir -p "$TMPDIR"; \curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash )`

Comment: I dont think it is normal for perlbrew to touch files in system directories like  `/usr/local/`. I remember that it normally works in `~/perl5/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [installation page](https://perlbrew.pl/Installation.html) lists an alternate installation method which worked for me:

```sh
sudo cpan App::perlbrew
perlbrew init
```