# Perlbrew fails to install new perl version

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I'm attempting to install a new perl version with perlbrew:

```
perlbrew install perl-5.34.1
```

but this produces the error:

```
Fetching perl 5.34.1 as /home/703404669/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.34.1.tar.gz
Download https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.34.1.tar.gz to /home/703404669/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.34.1.tar.gz
ERROR: Failed to download https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.34.1.tar.gz
ERROR: Failed to execute the command

    curl --silent --location --fail -o /home/703404669/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.34.1.tar.gz https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.34.1.tar.gz

Reason:

    5888
```

which I'm unable to find on Google searches.

I know that there isn't any typo, because when I intentionally write something wrong, I get a different error.

I have no idea why this is happening, nor to fix it.

EDIT:

the command

```
curl --location https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.34.1.tar.gz > /dev/null
```

outputs

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 17.3M  100 17.3M    0     0  68.5M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 68.5M
```

How can I install a perl version with perlbrew?

Comment: What do you get if you try to `curl --location https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHAY/perl-5.34.1.tar.gz > /dev/null`?

Comment: @choroba I've edited the question to show the output to your command

Comment: Does this help? https://bytemeta.vip/repo/gugod/App-perlbrew/issues/709

Comment: Exit code 5888 seems to be the same as exit code 23, according to [this](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2018-February/031498.html) post. Exit code 23 means *"Write error. Curl could not write data to a local filesystem or similar. curl receives data chunk by chunk from the network and it stores it like at (or writes it to stdout), one piece at a time. If that write action gets an error, this is the exit status."*, reference [here](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/returns)

Comment: I think you need to run `perlbrew init` first. Else the directories will be missing

Comment: @HåkonHægland indeed, that is the solution! If you write your solution down, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

`5888` is `0x1700`. This could be `$?` for a program that used `exit(0x17)`, which is to say `exit(23)`. `curl` uses that exit code when

> 23     Write error. Curl couldn't write data to a local filesystem or similar.

Sounds like it can't write to `/home/703404669/perl5/perlbrew/dists/perl-5.34.1.tar.gz`.

---

If the directory doesn't exist, maybe you didn't properly install `perlbrew`.

[Ways to install `perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/Installation.html):

```sh
\curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

```sh
\wget -O - https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

```sh
\fetch -o- https://install.perlbrew.pl | sh
```

```sh
sudo cpan App::perlbrew
perlbrew init
```

You also need to place a command in your shell's interactive startup script as instructed.

---

Or maybe you don't have enough disk space. Did you mean to install `perlbrew` somewhere other than `/home/703404669/perl5/perlbrew`?

> The default perlbrew root directory is `~/perl5/perlbrew`, which can be changed by setting `PERLBREW_ROOT` environment variable before the installation and initialization.

Comment: the problem was a missing `perlbrew init` but none of the errors that I received indicated that explicitly.

Comment: `perlbrew init` isn't normally needed. [`\curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash` is the normal way to install the tool.](https://perlbrew.pl/), and `perlbrew init` is only needed when using `cpan` or similar to download the module.

Comment: I had issues with that install command too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306986/attempt-to-install-perlbrew-fails describes the problem and the solution

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that it would not create the destination folder for that download. So what fixed it for me was:

mkdir $HOME/perl5/perlbrew/dists -p

In the above case just:

mkdir -p /home/703404669/perl5/perlbrew/dists